# Valgrind is complaining of memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a C program that takes flags and files on the command line. In order to process the files I put them in a dynamically allocated array of type `char**` it is when working with this array that Valgrind complains

```
==14389== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14389== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14389== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14389== Command: ./main
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x4838931: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x10931B: Options_append_filename (main.c:53)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Invalid write of size 8
==14389==    at 0x10934A: Options_append_filename (main.c:54)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389==  Address 0x4a53090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==14389==    at 0x483998B: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x1092DA: Options_append_filename (main.c:44)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483A9B8: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483A9C7: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483A9D9: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483A9E3: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483A9E5: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483A9F4: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109373: Options_append_filename (main.c:55)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Invalid write of size 8
==14389==    at 0x10938D: Options_append_filename (main.c:56)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389==  Address 0x4a53098 is 7 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==14389==    at 0x483998B: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x1092DA: Options_append_filename (main.c:44)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x1095AE: main (main.c:113)
==14389== 
==14389== Invalid read of size 8
==14389==    at 0x1095A8: main (main.c:113)
==14389==  Address 0x4a53098 is 7 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==14389==    at 0x483998B: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x1092DA: Options_append_filename (main.c:44)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x48C2F73: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483A852: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48C431D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483A864: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48C431D: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x48F1993: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1224)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x48F1995: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1226)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x48F19A6: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1224)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x48F19A8: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1226)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x48F19D0: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1224)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x48F19C4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1226)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483EA3F: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48F1951: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1243)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483EA57: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48F1951: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1243)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14389==    at 0x483EA5C: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48F1951: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1243)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483EA70: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48F1951: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1243)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
==14389== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14389==    at 0x483EA81: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x48F1951: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1243)
==14389==    by 0x48C3018: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1638)
==14389==    by 0x48CB995: printf (printf.c:33)
==14389==    by 0x1095E2: main (main.c:117)
==14389== 
opts.files[0] is: './main'
==14389== 
==14389== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14389==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==14389==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 1,040 bytes allocated
==14389== 
==14389== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==14389==    at 0x483998B: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x1092DA: Options_append_filename (main.c:44)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== 7 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==14389==    at 0x483774F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14389==    by 0x109349: Options_append_filename (main.c:54)
==14389==    by 0x1094B9: parse_cmdline (main.c:85)
==14389==    by 0x109544: main (main.c:98)
==14389== 
==14389== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14389==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==14389==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14389==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14389==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14389==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14389== 
==14389== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14389== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==14389== ERROR SUMMARY: 48 errors from 27 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I have tried playing around with initializing the array with data etc.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    bool help_flag;
    bool version_flag;
    char **files;
} Options;

Options Options_new() {
    Options opts;
    opts.help_flag = false;
    opts.version_flag = false;

    opts.files = malloc(sizeof(NULL));
    opts.files = NULL;
    return opts;
}

void Options_cleanup_mem(Options *opts) {
    int i = 0;
    while (opts->files[i] != NULL)
        i++;

    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        free(opts->files[j]);
    }
}

int Options_append_filename(Options *opts, char *filename) {
    int num_files = 0;
    char **tmp;
    while (opts->files[num_files] != NULL)
        num_files++;

    tmp = realloc(opts->files, num_files + 1);

    /* Handle case where realloc can't allocate memory */
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    opts->files = tmp;
    free(opts->files[num_files]);
    opts->files[num_files] = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
    strcpy(opts->files[num_files], filename);
    opts->files[num_files + 1] = NULL;

    return 0;
}

Options parse_cmdline(int argc, char **argv) {
    Options opts = Options_new();
    for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
        if (argv[a][0] == '-') {
            char *longopt = argv[a];
            if (!strcmp(longopt, "--help")) {
                opts.help_flag = true;
            } else if (!strcmp(longopt, "--version")) {
                opts.version_flag = true;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unkown option\n");
                Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            if (Options_append_filename(&opts, argv[a]) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error processing arguments\n");
                Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);
            }
        }
    }

    return opts;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Options opts = parse_cmdline(argc, argv);

    if (opts.help_flag) {
        printf("Help message\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (opts.version_flag) {
        printf("Version message\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (opts.files[i] != NULL)
        i++;

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
        printf("opts.files[%d] is: '%s'\n", a, opts.files[a]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is at least one memory leak here:

```
opts.files = malloc(sizeof(NULL));
opts.files = NULL;
```

You allocate memory for the size of `NULL`, which is meaningless as `NULL` can be defined as `0` or `((void*)0)` which may have different sizes, and you immediately overwrite this pointer with `opts.files = NULL`, making the allocated block unreachable. You should allocate space for one pointer and initialize it to `NULL`.

There is another leak in `Options_cleanup_mem`: you forget to free the array pointed to by `opts->files`.

The size passed in`tmp = realloc(opts->files, num_files + 1);` is incorrect, you should mutiply the number of elements by the element size `sizeof(opts->files[0])`. Furthermore, the new number of elements is `num_files + 2`, including the new filename and the null terminator.

The line `free(opts->files[num_files]);` is redundant in `Options_append_filename` since `opts->files[num_files]` is a `NULL` pointer.

You should exit the program in all error cases in `parse_cmdline()`.

You should free the allocated memory before returning from `main()` with `Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);` so valgrind does not diagnose unfreed memory.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    bool help_flag;
    bool version_flag;
    char **files;
} Options;

Options Options_new(void) {
    Options opts;
    opts.help_flag = false;
    opts.version_flag = false;

    opts.files = malloc(sizeof(opts.files[0]));
    opts.files[0] = NULL;
    return opts;
}

void Options_cleanup_mem(Options *opts) {
    int i = 0;
    if (opts->files) {
        while (opts->files[i] != NULL)
            free(opts->files[i++]);

        free(opts->files);
    }
}

int Options_append_filename(Options *opts, const char *filename) {
    int num_files = 0;
    char **tmp;
    while (opts->files[num_files] != NULL)
        num_files++;

    tmp = realloc(opts->files, sizeof(opts->files[0]) * (num_files + 2));

    /* Handle case where realloc can't allocate memory */
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    opts->files = tmp;
    opts->files[num_files] = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
    strcpy(opts->files[num_files], filename);
    opts->files[num_files + 1] = NULL;

    return 0;
}

Options parse_cmdline(int argc, char **argv) {
    Options opts = Options_new();
    for (int a = 0; a < argc; a++) {
        if (argv[a][0] == '-') {
            char *longopt = argv[a];
            if (!strcmp(longopt, "--help")) {
                opts.help_flag = true;
            } else if (!strcmp(longopt, "--version")) {
                opts.version_flag = true;
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unkown option\n");
                Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);
                exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            if (Options_append_filename(&opts, argv[a]) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error processing arguments\n");
                Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    return opts;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Options opts = parse_cmdline(argc, argv);

    if (opts.help_flag) {
        printf("Help message\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (opts.version_flag) {
        printf("Version message\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (opts.files[i] != NULL)
        i++;

    for (int a = 0; a < i; a++)
        printf("opts.files[%d] is: '%s'\n", a, opts.files[a]);

    Options_cleanup_mem(&opts);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- It is difficult to handle memory allocation failures when you return the `Options` structure by value. `Options_new` should take a pointer and return an error status.
- You test for `realloc()` failure, but not for other `malloc()` failures.
- You should store the array size inside the `Options` structure to avoid recomputing it everywhere.